# How to convert to global variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to do replication with Ansible.

But this code returns error:

```
- name: Semi-synchronous - Get the master status
  mysql_replication: mode=getmaster
  register: binlog
  when: hostname.stdout.find('usme-db-master') == 0

- name: Debug
  debug: var=binlog.File
  when: hostname.stdout.find('usme-db-slave') == 0
```

Output:

```
ASK [dbtier : Semi-synchronous - Get the master status] ***********************
skipping: [192.168.30.6] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}
ok: [192.168.30.5 -> 192.168.30.5] => {"Binlog_Do_DB": "", "Binlog_Ignore_DB": "", "Executed_Gtid_Set": "", "File": "usme-db-master-bin.000033", "Is_Master": true, "Position": 154, "changed": false}

TASK [dbtier : Debug] **********************************************************
skipping: [192.168.30.5] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}
ok: [192.168.30.6] => {
    "binlog.File": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

TASK Get the master is get a File and Position.
But the next task says `"binlog.File": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`

Maybe Ansible is distinguish between `usme-db-master` and `usme-db-slave`.

What should I do?

Version is 2.3.0

Comment: Use {{ }} in debug while using variable.  So var ="{{binlog.File}}"

Comment: @Shasha99 No, that's not the correct syntax. OP's usage is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your first task includes a conditional: you define register `binlog` **only** when `hostname.stdout.find('usme-db-master') == 0`.

In your run this condition is not met, so the task is skipped (thus `binlog` is **not** registered).

Your second task uses `binlog` fact when condition `when: hostname.stdout.find('usme-db-slave') == 0` is met.

This time, the condition is met and the task is executed. However, as the first task was skipped, `binlog` is not set, Ansible reports the error.

---

On top of the above logic flaw, to use a fact from one host on another one, you need to split your code into two plays and run them sequentially on each host. Then access the variable using `hostvars` in the following manner (you need to customise it, it's just an example):

```
- host: usme-db-master
  tasks:
    - name: Semi-synchronous - Get the master status
      mysql_replication: mode=getmaster
      register: binlog

- host: usme-db-slave
  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug: var=hostvars.usme-db-master.binlog.File
```